# Web Farm Framework - Adding servers are offline

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7.5, web-farm, iis

My problem is that im trying to setup a server farm but the nodes all come up as offline. I dont get a connection error saying that the servername is wrong, but get "offline" after it "test connection"

I have:
 - Setup firewalls rules to allow Remote and file share on Domain and private network
 - Installed WWF 2.0 on both servers
 - Account that im using is a domain account that is Administrator on both machines.

www01 is the same server as the controller below, but same results if i try www02 as primary.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selecting "server is available for loadbalancing" and it came up online. Wierd that we had to do that, we dont want to use the built in LB.